# Magento 2.3.0 Remove amazon pay button from different pages if current product in cart

Tags: frontend, catalog, products, magento2.3.0, amazon-payment

I need to develop a feature in my custom module, I would like to hide **Amazon pay button** from product page, cart page, mini cart, shipping page upon condition.

If the current product is in the cart then hide **Amazon pay button** from the product page, cart page, mini cart, shipping page.

How can I achieve these things?. can someone help me to achieve these things.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create preference.
You can create plugin for "isPwaButtonVisibleOnProductPage" instead of "isPaymentButtonEnabled" so that you will not need to create preference.

Comment: Update my question. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I do it my self!

Actualy there is a setting for display amazon button on product page, min cart, cart page, shipping method page and this all function manage by `Amazon\Core\Helper\Data` class function called **public function isPaymentButtonEnabled()**. and `Amazon\Payment\Block\Minicart\Button` class function called **protected function _toHtml()**.

So create plugin for **public function isPaymentButtonEnabled()** and create prefrance for **protected function _toHtml()**. My code will look like this.

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Amazon\Core\Helper\Data">
    <plugin name="hide_amzn_buttom_product_page_plugin" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin\ProductPageAmznButton" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
<preference for="Amazon\Payment\Block\Minicart\Button" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Minicart\CartPageAmznButton"/>
```

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Plugin/ProductPageAmznButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data;

class ProductPageAmznButton
{
    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param string $scope
     * @param null $scopeCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsPaymentButtonEnabled($subject, $result, $scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $scopeCode = null)
    {
        if($this->helper->isModuleEnable()){
            if($this->helper->hasProductIncart()){
                return false;
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Minicart/CartPageAmznButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Minicart;

use Amazon\Core\Helper\Data as AmazonCoreHelper;
use Amazon\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config;
use Amazon\Payment\Helper\Data;
use Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data as ModuleHelper;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CartPageAmznButton extends \Amazon\Payment\Block\Minicart\Button
{
    protected $moduleHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        Data $mainHelper,
        Session $session,
        Config $payment,
        AmazonCoreHelper $coreHelper,
        Http $request,
        ModuleHelper $moduleHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->moduleHelper = $moduleHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $localeResolver, $mainHelper, $session, $payment, $coreHelper, $request, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if($this->moduleHelper->isModuleEnable()){
            if($this->moduleHelper->hasProductInCart()){
                return '';
            }

        }
        if (!$this->shouldRender()) {
            return '';
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete answer? You're referencing a custom helper and calling a function that you didn't include.